# Workbox and Create react app doesn't serve new version of index.html

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker, workbox

I used `create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript` to init my pwa project. Keep most of the code from the template, which has:

`precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)`

I run into the problem that service worker doesn't detect new changes I made to a react app, as well as a new version of index.html. In addition, the react app is served from AWS S3

From my investigation, it looks like workbox doesn't give `index.html` a new post fix `__WB_REVISION`. I did the following steps:

1. Remove workbox pre-cache
2. Unregister the workbox via chrome dev console
3. Relead the page which re-register the service worker and new index.html is cached

Is there a way to have new `__WB_REVISION` postfix for every build or what could be a solution to force service worker to served a new index.html - could start with non userfriendly way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it has nothing to do with workbox, the problem is because of double caching. I found an idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367705/workbox-and-create-react-app-doesnt-serve-new-version-of-index-html#:%7E:text=10,using%20workbox.js).

In my case, where I deployed the react app to AWS S3 and served it with S3 + cloudfront. The way I solve the problem is invaliding the `service-worker.js` on new deploy.

Here is a small snippet with AWS CDK to solve the problem

```
    new s3Deployment.BucketDeployment(this, `${servicePrefix}-bucket-deployment`, {
      sources: [s3Deployment.Source.asset('./build')],
      destinationBucket: bucket,
      distribution,
      distributionPaths: ['/', '/index.html', '/service-worker.js'],
    });
```

The `distributionPaths` tells cloudfront to invalidate new service-worker.js for every new deployment